# PC continuously restarts or unable to turn on

Tags: bsod, reboot

My computer started showing BSODs, so I decided to reinstall Windows 7 to Windows 10. I installed all the necessary drivers and some games on Steam.

I was playing Squad for 1 hour and the PC turned off and then again on after boot I tried another game but when it loads PC turned off again, but this time only LEDs on PC starts and my molex fan, but my PWM fans and CPU fan didn't start and it showed nothing on the monitor just `No signal`. 
Next I turned off my PC but then it was unable to turn it on again just no sign of power.

Next I tried removing RAMs and start it with just one (I have 2 x Kingston HyperX 4GB), but still nothing so I tried clear CMOS and it somehow turned on and booted, but it turned off when I just started Chrome next I start Windows memory diagnostics tool, but after few seconds it rebooted again and started continuously rebooting, so I tried the second RAM stick and I was unable to turn on my PC.

When only my first RAM stick is plugged in and I clear CMOS PC continuously reboots or sometime it loads win and after some time it reboots again
When I plug only the second RAM stick I was unable to power on PC anyhow...

Do you have any idea what is wrong? Can it be both of RAM sticks or is it something else?

Specs:

- CPU: i5-4690k
- mobo: MSI Z97 gaming 3
- HDD: Seagate Desktop HDD
- RAM: 2x 4GB Kingston HyperX
- GPU: MSI GTX 960 - currently unpluged
- PSU: Corsair CX600M

Comment: Edited! And sorry for bad english

Comment: Your English is great, no need to say sorry. We can now read it and hopefully some one can help :)... The question is hard to answer, and you are probably better taking it to a PC repair shop. You've already tried using just 1 RAM stick, resetting the CMOS (+1 for your efforts) etc. When I first read this I thought it is a faulty CPU but CPU ususally works or doesn't work, and you're getting more intermittent. The fact it doesn't even boot up sometimes suggests issue is not with Harddrive... To me, the issue is possibly your PSU. Hopefully you can borrow one from work/a friend

Comment: It's my custom build so I will try to find bad component and send it back to shop cause all components are still in warranty... now I am going to visit my friend and try his RAM and PSU... but if you think it is PSU, why with  one of the RAM sticks it don't start, completly dead.. only with the second one it works sometimes when I clear CMOS..Anyway thanks for answer